# Azure DevOps: work item type rules triggered by Board Column

Tags: azure, azure-devops, rules

I would like to do changes to my work items automatically when working in Kanban board. For example, if I drag work item type to other column (changing Board Column field value) - I want to place a tag saying it's current Board Column value.

This is currently not available in Rules settings for work item types.

Where is the best place to put ADO Boards enhancement requests?

Comment: If you want to create a feature request you can make it [here on developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html)

Comment: You can use aggregator for this purpose: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-server-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement can be achieved by alternative. Generally, when you drag work item type to other column, the `state` filed is changed too. So you can create a tag filed and add rules to set tag value when `state` changed. Check the following steps:

1. Create a tag field:

[image]

2. Create rules for each state changed. For example:

[image]

By the way, if you have new ideas, you could submit suggestions at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: This is not an answer because this field does not behave likes tags. You cannot easily filter by it or color code it.